# I need help moving a sprite up and down when a key is pressed in Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

I am a new GameTechnology student and I have to recreate Pong as my first game. I'm currently working on moving the bars up and down when either "W", "S", Up or Down is pressed, but I can't seem to get it to work, can someone please help? This is my code up until now. I would really appreciate any help, though please keep it simple and explain because as I said, I am still new to this

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Pong
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D RightPlayer;
        Texture2D LeftPlayer;
        Texture2D Ball;
        Vector2 LeftPos;
        Vector2 RightPos;
        Vector2 BallPos;
        KeyboardState currentKBState, previousKBState = Keyboard.GetState();
        int Ypos1;    
        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Ypos1 = 50;
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            RightPlayer = Content.Load<Texture2D>("rodeSpeler");
            LeftPlayer = Content.Load<Texture2D>("blauweSpeler");
            Ball = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bal");
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();
            LeftPos = Vector2.Zero;
            if (currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && previousKBState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up))
            {
                Ypos1 = Ypos1 - 500;

                    }
            LeftPos = new Vector2(0, Ypos1);
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
        
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(LeftPlayer, LeftPos, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();    
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the value of 500 from? What unit is it in?

Comment: I use the value of YPos1 for the Y position of the LeftPlayer sprite. I just took 500 to see a significant difference. I don't know if I have to add a unit?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take your time to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Please, explain what is the current wrong result/behavior with your implementation, and what is the desired effect.

Comment: I am trying to get my sprite (LeftPlayer) to move up when I press up, I increased the amount to 500 to see if anything changed. But whenever I press up, it does nothing

Answer (score 2):

There are four issues with your code. Since this is a homework problem I will only give hints.

1. The units are in pixels per step, 60 times per second, depending on the `if` above it. So moving 500 would most likely move it off of the screen.
2. `LeftPos` already contains a Y component: `LeftPos.Y`, eliminating the need for the `Ypos1` variable.
3. Some of the variables that you are using will always have the default values. You are missing two assignments in Update(). Once corrected you will find that one of these is not needed at all, due to a logic error in the behavior as written.
4. Are you setting a variable to a fixed value every step, that shouldn't be?

I like to manually(i.e. hand-written) make a chart of the variables and follow each loop of the game to see if the values correspond to my expectations. This technique can be confirmed in Visual Studio by placing Checkpoints (Click on the bar on the far left of a line of code) at the start of Update and use F11 to Step Into each line hovering over each variable to check its value.

Hopefully this puts you on the right path to discovering the issues.